# Custom pagination in wp

Tags: pagination

I am new in Wp, can you please tell me ,is it possible to pagination like this design.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use paginate_links (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) to output pagination. You'll need some additional CSS to style the links however.

Comment: Zakalwe ,Can you give me code which can give same output.

Comment: @Shiva It's Q&A site and not "I can't do it, do it for me pls" site. According to rules, you have to research your problem first and then ask precise question. Not spam the site with a bunch o things you want to do and wait until users will write code for you...